# Що таке кропивниця в пісні "Комарик"

Tags: значення-слів

Що таке кропивниця в цій пісні:

> Сталін хрест нап'яв, взяв кадильницю,
>   ходить бродить до УПА по *кропивницю*.
>
> Ех *кропивниця*, ти моя ладная,
>   скорострільная, самозарядная.

Очевидно, що якась зброя, можливо гвинтівка, або її повстанська модифікація.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Текст пісні](http://maidan.org.ua/arch/hum/1238922382.html) згадує не *кропивниця*, а *кропильниця*.

> **Кропильниця**, **і**, *жін*. Посудина для свяченої води, у яку вмочають [кропило](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE). *На столі стояла здорова кропильниця з водою.., лежав хрест та чорніло кропило* (Нечуй-Левицький, IV, 1956, 99); *Черниці взяли за вушка велику металеву кропильницю* (Іван Микитенко, II, 1957, 375).
>
> <sup>[Словник української мови: в 11 тт. / АН УРСР. Інститут мовознавства; за ред. І. К. Білодіда. — К.: Наукова думка, 1970—1980. — Т. 4. — С. 366.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F)</sup>

---

*Моя думка.* Спочатку згадують *кропильницю* в словниковому сенсі: червоний тиран Джугашвілі ж бо хреста напʼяв — удавав святою людиною, але з натяком на те, що диктатор Джугашвілі бродив не по нею — не визволяв, ще й кадильницею розмахував — покривав злим димом землю.

А потім мовлять, типу йому покажуть ту самую *кропильницю* — дасти відсіч.